# How to pass image path in js function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I'm trying to pass the image path dynamically from one JSP page to another using a JS function, but the image path I get in a JS `alert` is different. The correct path is `.\Products\767\76\suitmed.jpg` however the alert shows me this `.\Products>7>suitmed.jpg`. Can some one please help me with this.

[image]

ProductDiv.jsp

```html
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="products">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <!--here in this Image tag I was trying to pass the path od med and large img from product obj -->
                    <img src="${products.smallImage}" onclick="getImageDetails('${products.mediumImage}', '${products.largeImage}'); return false;" alt="${products.productId}+productImage" />
                    <h2>${products.allPrice}</h2>
                    <p>${products.name}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choose">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
                            Add to Wishlist
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Product.Js

```
function getImageDetails(mediumImagePath, LargeImagePath) {
    alert(mediumImagePath + "_______" + LargeImagePath);
    $("#bigImage").attr("src", mediumImagePath);
}
```

Product details.Jsp

```html
<div class="view-product" >
    <img class="fancybox" id="bigImage" src="" data-big="images/home/suitlarge.jpg" /></br>
    <!--<img src="images/product-details/1.jpg" alt="" /> -->
    <h3>ZOOM</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect element and check the `onclick` attribute..

Comment: I've uploaded image screenshot of onclick element with ques  you can reffer from that

Comment: JSP won't escape special javascript escape sequences, like `'\76'` (which is eqauls to `'>'`). You could try something like `<img src="..." data-image-medium="${products.mediumImage}" onclick="getImageDetails(this.getAttribute('data-image-medium'), ...); return false;" alt="..." />`

Comment: Don't ever user backslashes `\\`` for paths on the web, even on a Windows servers,  always use forward slashes `/`

Answer (score 0):

Never programmed jsp, but here is a plausible explanation:

\## is interpreted as an octal character escape sequence.

```
Char    Octal   Dec Hex Description
<        74     60  3c  Less than sign (&lt; in HTML)
=        75     61  3d  Equals sign
>        76     62  3e  Greater than sign (&gt; in HTML)
?        77     63  3f  Question mark
```

so "\76" becomes ">" when printing..

try replacing all "\" with "/" in paths that usually helps you out, and most webservices can already handle the translation from unix styled paths to windows styled..